# Determine if a linux port supports cmpxchg in hardware

Tags: linux, compilation, linux-kernel

I am writing a Linux kernel patch which uses cmpxchg to speed up a few cases besides fixing a few semantic issues, However I've noted that certain architectures only support xchg and not cmpxchg, How do i determine at compile time if the architecture the kernel is being compiled for supports cmpxchg in hardware or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `#ifdef __HAVE_ARCH_CMPXCHG` ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @stealthyninja Hmmm? As far as I see, this is exactly the answer. The fact that it ends with a question mark is a matter of style. [Rhetorical Question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question)

Comment: @stealthyninja There used to be a time with more creative flag comments. Now all I see is this endlessly copy-pasted text :-(

Comment: @cnicutar - there still is, I think SO just fills that in for pre-selected options when you review an answer.

Comment: Hmm, linux seems to be a mess ? ARM port clearly has cmpxchg since ARMv6 but the identifier search doesn't show it as declared, I will make sure to include this in the patch notice. Thanks :)

Comment: @stealthyninja Sorry, I didn't now SO fills that in :-)